# How can I set the HTTP status code?

Tags: plugin-development, controller, ajax

I'm trying to set a 404 HTTP status response code for an ajax controller action in a plugin.

Yii has a response object where the code can be set, but I can't find a way to access it from craft.

Answer (score 6):

I believe [HeaderHelper::setHeader()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/helpers/HeaderHelper#setHeader-detail) is what you're looking for in the context of a plugin.

Answer (score 6):

In Craft3, the correct way of setting HTTP status codes is

`Craft::$app->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);`

Answer (score 3):

```
HeaderHelper::setHeader(array('status' => 404));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
http_response_code(404);
return $this->returnErrorJson('Something happened, try again.');
```